# Griddler config undefined method processor_class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, griddler

I created config/initializers/griddler.rb per the github's instructions:

```
Griddler.configure do |config|
  config.processor_class = EmailProcessor
  config.to = :email # :full, :email, :hash 
  config.reply_delimiter = '-- REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE --'
  config.email_service = :mandrill
end
```

On running I get this error:

```
 /app/config/initializers/griddler.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `processor_class=' for #<Griddler::Configuration:0x00000004b1eb18> (NoMethodError)
```

The file is located at ./config/initializers/griddler.rb . I'm not sure why it shows /app there.

Comment: Tested with a fresh install, same issue.

Comment: What version of the griddler gem are you using?

Comment: Not specifying the version.. I just installed it 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Ah.. .2, hm. The github references .5

Comment: Not being on the latest was the problem.. trying this on my main project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely are using an outdated version of the Griddler gem, which did not have this API. Try upgrading to the latest version of the [Griddler gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/griddler) (0.5.0 as of this writing).

Comment: Thanks Stuart!
Why did gem 'griddler' install .2 and not .5?

Comment: Could be that another gem in your bundle had a shared dependency, and Bundler's dependency resolution algorithm determined that 0.2.x was the only one that would satisfy all requirements. You'll probably have to check the gems that Griddler depends on to figure that out, or run `DEBUG_RESOLVER=y bundle install` to see verbose output from Bundler's dependency resolution process.